# How to erase Ubuntu and reinstall windows 10 on a single-booted system

Tags: windows-10

I want to reinstall Windows 10 from Ubuntu but I don't know how. It's single booted and I have Windows 10 on a USB ready to go I just don't know how to actually boot it into Windows 10.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about installing Windows from a USB drive, something that can be done without any connection to Ubuntu at all.

Comment: You just need to change the boot order in the bios and boot from the USB. Search for "how do I boot from a USB", you should get dozens of tutorials. It's really simple, but isn't related to Ubuntu at all.

Answer (score 0):

### Installing Windows 10 without USB using Ubuntu GRUB

- Backup the Target drive.
- Create a 6GB NTFS partition on the hard drive and extract the Windows ISO to it.
- Create a 20GB, or larger, NTFS partition on the hard drive for the Windows Installation.
- Open Disks, (Gnome-Disks), and note Device, (/dev/sdx), and UUID of the Windows ISO extract partition.
- For msdos partition table, copy the following menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40-custom/`*:

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sda4)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-592C85254E2CD0B7' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  592C85254E2CD0B7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 592C85254E2CD0B7
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

- Edit menuentry, changing `sda4 to sdax`, `msdos4` to `msdosx` (4 places), and 592C85254E2CD0B7 to UUID, (3 places), to suit step 4 above.
- Run `sudo update grub` confirm that `ntldr /bootmgr` appears in grub.cfg.
- Boot the computer into the newly created Windows menuentry and install Windows into it's new partition.
- Reinstall Ubuntu if desired, the GRUB bootloader will have been replaced with the Windows bootloader.

*For gpt partition table, copy the following menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40-custom/`:

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sdc1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-5642BC722509341F' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  5642BC722509341F
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5642BC722509341F
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

**Boot selecting Windows from the GRUB menu and follow the instructions.**

**Limitations**

Windows 10 has limitations with respect to partition tables and boot modes.

I was able to install Legacy mode Windows to a drive with a MSDOS partition table.

I was able to install UEFI mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table.

I was not able to install Legacy mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table.

I was not able to install UEFI mode Windows to a drive with a GPT partition table and Legacy mode Ubuntu.

There may be workarounds that are outside the scope of this answer.